# xev Alt key change, but Alt key doesn't work

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, xmodmap, xev

I want to chage special key alt, crtl, hanja(in the multy language)

because I Used ibus, I try to change my keymap by Xkb not xmap.
after searching on internet I just to exchange my keycode on

```
/usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev   

<LALT> = 131; //original code : 64
<LCTL> = 64;  //original code :37
<HJCV> = 37;  //original code  :131
```

it work. except "LALT" 
when I check my key input, it looks fine, 
but LALT does not combine other fucntional key(ex ALT+TAB, ALT+F4)

when I push the LCTL(should act the 'HJCV') it work.
but when I push the HJCV (shold act the 'ALT') it doesn't work

when I see the xev, it looks fine

```
state 0x18, keycode 131 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 108
```

to find out the answer, I swaping the LALT, RALT position in 'altwin'

```
 /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/altwin
```

but still, my HJCV(now ALT_R) doesn't wokr even my ALT_R(ALT_L) is fine.
I check the 'xev' again, and I found something

```
state 0x18, keycode 131 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 108

state 0x10, keycode 108 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
```

keycode 108(ALT_R) succefully chagned ALT_L but my HJCV(ALT_L)is remain
(even returns keycode 108, it doesn't work)

only thing I can find difference is state, I think I have something with 'state' but I don't know

how can I solved it ?